# Booking.com Cancellation fees

Tags: germany, bookings, cancellations, booking.com

Before you read this question let it be known that this question has been asked before on this site; however, I find that my situation is slightly different then the others.

I recently was searching for places to stay in Germany and I found an apartment that I wanted to book. It looked nice and it was available for the time I wanted, so I booked it.  On the site it said that payments could only be made in cash for booking this apartment and ultimately the reason I decided to go ahead and book this place was that it stated on booking.com that the host will contact you after booking to handle everything from payments to questions.

Before booking I searched the entire site for the hosts contact information so I could ask further questions about the apartment that I did not see on the booking.com website.  I even google searched for this apartment to see if it was listed anywhere else so I could possibly contact the host before booking. On booking.com it did state that there could be cancelation fees if I do decide to cancel at any point. I am new to booking.com and did not have an account it allowed me to book the property without providing any credit card information and as soon as the booking went through shortly after they provided me with the host's contact info. I asked my question and sure enough I wanted to cancel so I went to hit cancel on booking.com. It told me to ask the host for the process of canceling since there could be cancelation fees, I asked the host if I could cancel.  He sent me a picture of a piece of paper stating a cancelation fee is required.  The host only accepts cash payments.  Am I legally bound to travel to Germany and pay this person now?  I had the apartment booked for under an hour.

Comment: Never book something unless you're sure that it's what you want: your booking forms a contract. In practical terms, it's very unlikely to be worth the host's time and effort suing you from another country. Also, unreasonable contracts are not enforceable ("unreasonable" includes there being no way to find out what the terms of the contract are before agreeing to it, and not including reasonable ways to discharge the debt; travelling across the world to pay cash is unlikely to be held to be reasonable).

Comment: If there is an organization like the UK Citizens Advice Bureau in your country, it might be worth talking to them to put your mind at ease.